# How to call Inner Class?

Tags: python, oop, python-object

Is there any difference between call `Person.Name()` and `self.Name()` despite `Person.Name()` being more readable?

```
class Person:
    class Name:
        def __init__(self, first_name, last_name):
            self.first_name = first_name
            self.last_name = last_name

        def __str__(self):
            return f'{self.first_name}, {self.last_name}'

    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name):
        self.name = Person.Name(first_name, last_name)
```

Comment: The only situation where they'd be different is if you had another class that inherited from `Person` and overrode the definition of `Name`. That said, nested classes are generally not very useful in Python. Why not move the `Name` class outside of `Person` and just call `Name()` without any prefix at all?

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive answer. I didn't though about inheriting case. 
I do not nest them normally, today I was just testing it because of curiosity.

Comment: `self.Name` can refer to an instance attribute that shadows `Person.Name`. If there is no such instance attribute, an `AttributeError` is avoided by looking for a class attribute named `Name`. Be explicit, and use `Person.Name` because that's the attribute you *want*, even if there is an instance attribute called `Name`.